# Cant fit list of tuples to dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a `list` of `tuples` with name `a`

```py
[('39965983', 'Mugshots.com ID'), ('11/07/1974', 'Birth date'), ('Compliant', 'Status'), ('White', 'Race'), ('Male', 'Gender'), ('38', 'Age'), ('5′ 9″ (1.75 m)', 'Height'), ('245 lb (111 kg)', 'Weight'), ('Brown', 'Eyes'), ('Brown', 'Hair'), ('521 OLD HIGHWAY 75', 'Address'), ('ONEONTA', 'City'), ('Alabama', 'State'), ('35121', 'Zip'), ('No', 'Address is Temporary'), ('5/29/2012', 'Address Last Verified'), ('5/26/2006', 'Registration Date'), ('N/A', 'Scars / Marks / Tattoos'), ('20040921', 'Released'), ('39965553', 'Mugshots.com ID'), ('11/09/1961', 'Birth date'), ('Compliant', 'Status'), ('Black', 'Race'), ('Male', 'Gender'), ('51', 'Age'), ('6′ 0″ (1.83 m)', 'Height'), ('220 lb (100 kg)', 'Weight'), ('Brown', 'Eyes'), ('Black', 'Hair'), ('314 DENSON RD', 'Address'), ('HAYDEN', 'City'), ('Alabama', 'State'), ('35079', 'Zip'), ('No', 'Address is Temporary'), ('5/15/2012', 'Address Last Verified'), ('11/09/2007', 'Registration Date'), ('N/A', 'Scars / Marks / Tattoos'), ('N/A', 'Aliases'), ('20050411', 'Released'), ('39965949', 'Mugshots.com ID'), ('6/17/1974', 'Birth date'), ('Compliant', 'Status'), ('White', 'Race'), ('Male', 'Gender'), ('38', 'Age'), ('6′ 0″ (1.83 m)', 'Height'), ('190 lb (86 kg)', 'Weight'), ('Green', 'Eyes'), ('Brown', 'Hair'), ('639 COUNTY HWY 55', 'Address'), ('BLOUNTSVILLE', 'City'), ('Alabama', 'State'), ('35031', 'Zip'), ('No', 'Address is Temporary'), ('3/02/2012', 'Address Last Verified'), ('6/16/2009', 'Registration Date'), ('N/A', 'Scars / Marks / Tattoos'), ('N/A', 'Aliases'), ('19971220', 'Released'), ('39965930', 'Mugshots.com ID'), ('3/12/1954', 'Birth date'), ('Compliant', 'Status'), ('White', 'Race'), ('Male', 'Gender'), ('58', 'Age'), ('6′ 0″ (1.83 m)', 'Height'), ('170 lb (77 kg)', 'Weight'), ('Hazel', 'Eyes'), ('Brown', 'Hair'), ('203 YOUNG ROAD', 'Address'), ('REMLAP', 'City'), ('Alabama', 'State'), ('35133', 'Zip'), ('No', 'Address is Temporary'), ('3/26/2012', 'Address Last Verified'), ('5/07/2002', 'Registration Date'), ('N/A', 'Aliases'), ('20000804', 'Released')]
```

And I would like to be able create csv file with header of tuple's second value and first values as values belonging to the header and 'none' if there is not value for that row.

```
items = []

curr_dict = None

for key in rest.keys():
    new_key = rest[key]
    new_value = key if key else 'None'

    if new_key == 'url':
        curr_dict = {}
        items.append(curr_dict)

    curr_dict[new_key] = new_value

df = pd.DataFrame(items).fillna('None')
df.to_csv("file.csv", index = False)
```

I tried code above, but I'm not able to fit the `a` to the code without losing data (because of doubled values in dict) or get NoneType error for `curr_dict[new_key] = new_value`

Comment: Because `dictionaries` cannot have duplicate `keys`. In your data there are duplicate keys, e.g. `Compliant`, as the `dict` can only have one `Compliant` other occurences of `Compliant` are overwritten.

Comment: you can use `dict(a)` btw

Comment: Try: `dct[j] = i` that will fix the ordering. But your data has multiple records.  As per @SayandipDutta's comment, you would *still* be overwriting one person's record with the next.

Comment: thanks for the coments, I would like to use second value in tuple as header in csv and add all first values, and none if it doesnt exist, how could I do it?

Comment: @AndrejovicAndrej That’s a new question entirely. If you do create a new question, your post should be _far_ more detailed than that. As an aside, if that is your goal, why do you say in your post that you don’t want to swap (or invert the order of) the keys and values?

Comment: Thanks for the msg, I changed the question! So can answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
t = [('39965983', 'Mugshots.com ID'), ('11/07/1974', 'Birth date'), ('Compliant', 'Status'), ('White', 'Race'), ('Male', 'Gender'), ('38', 'Age'), ('5′ 9″ (1.75 m)', 'Height'), ('245 lb (111 kg)', 'Weight'), ('Brown', 'Eyes'), ('Brown', 'Hair'), ('521 OLD HIGHWAY 75', 'Address'), ('ONEONTA', 'City'), ('Alabama', 'State'), ('35121', 'Zip'), ('No', 'Address is Temporary'), ('5/29/2012', 'Address Last Verified'), ('5/26/2006', 'Registration Date'), ('N/A', 'Scars / Marks / Tattoos'), ('20040921', 'Released'), ('39965553', 'Mugshots.com ID'), ('11/09/1961', 'Birth date'), ('Compliant', 'Status'), ('Black', 'Race'), ('Male', 'Gender'), ('51', 'Age'), ('6′ 0″ (1.83 m)', 'Height'), ('220 lb (100 kg)', 'Weight'), ('Brown', 'Eyes'), ('Black', 'Hair'), ('314 DENSON RD', 'Address'), ('HAYDEN', 'City'), ('Alabama', 'State'), ('35079', 'Zip'), ('No', 'Address is Temporary'), ('5/15/2012', 'Address Last Verified'), ('11/09/2007', 'Registration Date'), ('N/A', 'Scars / Marks / Tattoos'), ('N/A', 'Aliases'), ('20050411', 'Released'), ('39965949', 'Mugshots.com ID'), ('6/17/1974', 'Birth date'), ('Compliant', 'Status'), ('White', 'Race'), ('Male', 'Gender'), ('38', 'Age'), ('6′ 0″ (1.83 m)', 'Height'), ('190 lb (86 kg)', 'Weight'), ('Green', 'Eyes'), ('Brown', 'Hair'), ('639 COUNTY HWY 55', 'Address'), ('BLOUNTSVILLE', 'City'), ('Alabama', 'State'), ('35031', 'Zip'), ('No', 'Address is Temporary'), ('3/02/2012', 'Address Last Verified'), ('6/16/2009', 'Registration Date'), ('N/A', 'Scars / Marks / Tattoos'), ('N/A', 'Aliases'), ('19971220', 'Released'), ('39965930', 'Mugshots.com ID'), ('3/12/1954', 'Birth date'), ('Compliant', 'Status'), ('White', 'Race'), ('Male', 'Gender'), ('58', 'Age'), ('6′ 0″ (1.83 m)', 'Height'), ('170 lb (77 kg)', 'Weight'), ('Hazel', 'Eyes'), ('Brown', 'Hair'), ('203 YOUNG ROAD', 'Address'), ('REMLAP', 'City'), ('Alabama', 'State'), ('35133', 'Zip'), ('No', 'Address is Temporary'), ('3/26/2012', 'Address Last Verified'), ('5/07/2002', 'Registration Date'), ('N/A', 'Aliases'), ('20000804', 'Released')]

d = {x[0]: {} for x in t if x[1] == 'Mugshots.com ID'}

for x in t:
    if x[1] == 'Mugshots.com ID':
        curr_id = x[0]
    else:
        d[curr_id][x[1]] = x[0]

df = pd.DataFrame(d).fillna('None').transpose()
df.to_csv("file.csv")
```

Which gives the following output:

```
>>> df
          Birth date     Status  ...  Released Aliases
39965983  11/07/1974  Compliant  ...  20040921     N/A
39965553  11/09/1961  Compliant  ...  20050411     N/A
39965949   6/17/1974  Compliant  ...  19971220     N/A
39965930   3/12/1954  Compliant  ...  20000804     N/A

[4 rows x 19 columns]
```

And in the .csv:

[image]

Comment: thank you! this is what I was trying to do for like 3 days!